# Editing out inappropriate remarks to an otherwise reasonable answer

Tags: discussion, support, editing, low-quality-posts

I was reviewing the "Low Quality Post" queue and came across an answer from a new user that (a) criticized a comment on the post and (b) gave a link to a reasonably good explanation of the answer.  The post already had a comment that it is inappropriate to criticize posts (and also inappropriate to use an answer to comment).  The user had too little rep to actually comment.

My question: Is it reasonable for me to edit the post by just deleting the inappropriate critical comments of another user?  I realize that the best case scenario is for the user who made the comment to delete it themselves.  The reason I ask is that I hesitate to delete the post (since it contains some good/useful/relevant material), but I feel like it shouldn't be left "as is."  In this case, I skipped (since I didn't know what to do) but figured I ask for future reference.

Comment: Why do you think that it is "is inappropriate to criticize posts"? *Constructve* criticism is essential to teaching, and so is essential here.

Comment: @BillDubuque, Constructive criticism is ok provided that it is done in an appropriate way.  I could say "Actually, xxx is a counter-example to yyy" which seems fine.  Or, I could say " The #!@ #!@ answerer is wrong because he #!@ didn't consider the yyy counter-example the the #!@ question."  In this case, I think it is clearly not an appropriate way to answer.  The case I encountered wasn't so obvious because of the lack of expletives, but it certainly contained unnecessary off-putting verbage.

Answer (score 5):

If you see something in the Low Quality queue that can be salvaged by editing, then by all means edit it. Please.

(I do mean *salvaged*; if the post will not become a legitimate answer even after an edit, then don't bother. Minor edits to doomed posts are more harmful than useful.)

Comment: This is one of those meta-down-votes where it then is anyones guess what it is that the voter meant: Better delete away. Edit "doomed posts" too. There are no doomed posts. Too much editing is generally bad.  Who knows?